# How to request location authorization without creating an CLLocationManager instance?

Tags: ios, ios8, core-location

In iOS 8 Apple made us to explicitly call `request***Authorizaton` in order to request authorization. I created a CLLocationManager property, but I don't want to do this, because it would be a waste if I declared a property just to call one method at one time. I tried to create a local instance of `CLLocationManager` and call the method, but the alert view appears and disappears. I have a MapView, too, so I don't need to get location from the CLLocationManager. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're requesting authorization for location monitoring, presumably you would want to actually _get_ the location, no? If you're only using a location manager for this one call, you probably don't need one at all.

Comment: But in iOS 8, you need to do this in order to request authorization. It is not like in iOS 7 or 6. Apple changed this.

Comment: For the person that decremented my question's point, could you explain why you did so? I could edit my question.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time at looking at this question. I believe that as long as I don't call startUpdatingLocation method on my CLLocationManager instance, I won't be wasting too much performance. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it an instance variable so that it's retained while the dialog is displayed.

It disappears because it's not retained. You could use other tricks but they would be more wasteful in term of lines of code.